# Grouping items of the same category type in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this method that returns the services being offered

```
public function order_services(){
    
    $services = DB::select('select * from services');
    return view('guests/services',['services'=>$services]);;

}
```

and i am displaying like this

```
<ul class="list-group" id="myUl">
   @foreach ($services as $service)
   <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border border-danger"><span  style="font-size:24px; color:red
      "><i class="bi bi-check-circle font-weight-bold "></i></span> <span style="font-weight:bold" id="service_category">{{ $service->service_category }}</span><span><u><i class="bi bi-magic"></i></u></span></li>
   <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><span class="product_name" style="font-size:24px; color:#870FD1" data-price="349.34"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></span> <span class="product_name" id="service_name" data-price="{{ $service->service_price }}" data-category="{{ $service->service_category }}" >{{ $service->service_name }}</span><span class="text-success"><u>Available</u></span></li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

My table has `service_name` and `service_category`

I would like to display `service_category` as header and all the services under that category. Can this be done within blade or do i need to format the results in my controller first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grouping the list with php (in controller of blade into @php directive):

```
$list = [];
foreach($services as $item) {
  $list[$item->service_category][] = $item;
}
```

Updated method

```
public function order_services(){
    

    $services=  DB::table('services')
            ->selectRaw('id,service_name,service_category,service_price')
            ->orderBy('service_category')
            ->get();
            
    $list = [];
    foreach($services as $item) {
      $list[$item->service_category][] = $item;
    }
    
    return view('guests/services',['list'=>$list]);

}
```

And you can use $list in blade for display the result:

```
@foreach ($list as $category => $item)
  <h2>{{ $category }}</h2>
   <ul class="list-group" id="myUl">
     @foreach ($item as $service)
       <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border border-danger"><span  style="font-size:24px; color:red
      "><i class="bi bi-check-circle font-weight-bold "></i></span> <span style="font-weight:bold" id="service_category">{{ $service->service_category }}</span><span><u><i class="bi bi-magic"></i></u></span></li>
       <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><span class="product_name" style="font-size:24px; color:#870FD1" data-price="349.34"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></span> <span class="product_name" id="service_name" data-price="{{ $service->service_price }}" data-category="{{ $service->service_category }}" >{{ $service->service_name }}</span><span class="text-success"><u>Available</u></span></li>
     @endforeach
   </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get this error `Call to a member function groupBy() on array`

Comment: Sorry, the first way is not the way you want. so I delete it. because in group with the database, it will get back just one result of every group and we don't want it.

Comment: No change to what i was having. Same result as my original code.

Comment: which one did you test? Just test this new edited one and comment me the result.

Comment: I was wrong in @ foreach ($services as $service). I changed it to @ foreach ($item as $service). try this one please.

Comment: Still the same...

Comment: have you changed to the my last update?

Comment: what do you mean about the same?